# E-mail and country code in admin sales

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid

In my Magento Sales admin grid i would like to have an email and country so I created a code to make it possible:

```
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id'))
        ->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('order'=>'sales_flat_order'),
            'order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
            array('order.customer_email')
    );
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

and  to display columns:

```
    $this->addColumn('customer_email', array(
        'header' => $this->helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
        'index' => 'customer_email',
        'filter_index' => 'order.customer_email',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Country Id'),
        'index' => 'country_id',
        'width' => '25px',
        'align' => 'center',
        'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.country_id',
    ));
```

once I added and saved this code  everything seems to work until trying to search order by ID (increment_id)
then Magento throws me an error:

> `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_order.increment_id' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT`main_table`.*,`sales_flat_order_address`.`telephone`,`sales_flat_order_address`.`city`,`sales_flat_order_address`.`postcode`,`sales_flat_order_address`.`country_id`,`order`.`customer_email`FROM`sales_flat_order_grid`AS`main_table
>    `INNER JOIN`sales_flat_order_address`ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id
>    LEFT JOIN`sales_flat_order`AS`order`ON order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id WHERE (sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing') ORDER BY sales_flat_order.increment_id ASC LIMIT 20`

so I checked sales_flat_order to make sure there is a column named `increment_id` and it is there but it does not contain (it seems) correct increment_id but something ... else ... series of numbers anyhow not resembling expected number.

What I've done wrong ... please help.